# How to get random item from an blogger XML array?

Tags: arrays, xml, loops, blogger

I have this blogger for loop, and i wanna get a random item. how can i do that please ?

is there a way to shuffle the array and get the first item then break the loop ?

or generate a random number ?

```
<b:loop values='["1111","2222","3333"]' var='myArray' index='i'>
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  As explained in the [tour], this site is a repository of useful questions and their answers, ***not a help forum***.  
Please take the [tour], visit the [help] and especially read [ask] and [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236/18157) to learn how to use this site effectively.

Comment: post some code except single line of it

Answer (score 0):

You can use `index` attribute to get index of array but there is no way in Blogger to shuffle array or generate a random number, use JavaScript to manipulate results.

The following code will print the first item

```
<b:loop values='["1111","2222","3333"]' var='myArray' index='i'>
    <b:if cond='data:i == 0'>
      <data:myArray/>
    </b:if>
</b:loop>
```